# Is there a physics Puzzles site like Project Euler?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a site that publishing riddles and problems such as [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) 
publishes problems in computer science. Is there any similar site that is hardcore in the area of physics?

[This site](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/) has some good problems set, but it seems like there isn't a community and sharing of solutions/ideas like in Project Euler.

Comment: Could consider an Area51 for this. There's a [puzzing beta](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). I'd support a dedicated physics problems/solutions SE site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the Harvard physics problems of the week are pretty nice:

[Link](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/undergrad/problems)

Comment: Those problems seem to have ended back in 2004. Are they still posting new ones somewhere?

Comment: @MartyGreen I don't know if they are still posting new ones, would be great if the author would start posting new problems again. Perhaps someone should ask him to do so...

Answer (score 7):

One nice source of physics problems is books which catalog questions from graduate school qualifying exams.  For example:

- [University of Chicago Graduate Problems in Physics with Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226121097)
- [Princeton Problems in Physics with Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691024499)

Another source of tricky problems is:

- [Boston Area Undergraduate Physics Competition](http://liquids.seas.harvard.edu/oleg/competition/prev.html).

The contest is sadly extinct, but problems (and solutions!) from the contests that took place 1995 - 2004 are available online.

Comment: In the same vein, [Yung-Kuo Lim](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AYung-Kuo%20) compiles a large repertoire of graduate qualifying exam questions. A quick search will find you [this PDF](http://paginas.fisica.uson.mx/laura.yeomans/tc/YKL.pdf) on Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just like the example student offered, this one isn't active any more, but makes a nice compilation:

[Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120107064206/star.tau.ac.il/QUIZ/)

Answer (score 2):

You might also try this site for a "physics problem of the week" kind of thing: [www.fearofphysics.com](http://www.fearofphysics.com), although the problems seem like they've been running for just a couple of months.