# What are some good Physics olympiad papers to practice

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I am currently preparing for my National Physics Olympiad which happens to be the Indian physics olympiads. I have completed its previous papers and I want to solve more papers, I do not want to finish APHO papers right now as they are not of to much relevance to my National olympiad as APHO consists of a lot of mathematics. Can someone tell me more olympiads with papers available I can solve beside IPHO and APHO?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22696/2451 and links therein.