# Mechanics problems book

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Please suggest me some books on Problems in Classical Mechanics.

P.S. - Please suggest books of the level high school or pre college or at max first year college books.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22696/2451 and links therein.