# Are there any best websites for physics problems to enhance problem solving skills?

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

I actually prepare for International physics olymiad. Can anyone please tell me what are the best websites for physics problems (like codeforces, hackerrank, codechef)?

Comment: If you specifically want sites that feed you a problem at a time, the best are probably [PhysOlymp](https://physolymp.com/) and [Isaac Physics](https://isaacphysics.org/). But I think the best resources for Olympiads are still books, and handouts such as [Jaan Kalda's](https://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22696/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20832/2451 and links therein.